# not able to install packages with requirements.txt in docker

Tags: python, docker, numpy, tensorflow, pip

i am creating image with below dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /usr/app/
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
 hash pip && \
 pip install -r requirements.txt
Add . /usr/app/
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

requirements file:

```
altair==4.1.0
cmdstanpy==1.0.8
h5py==3.1.0
keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
matplotlib==3.4.2
numpy
opt-einsum==3.3.0
pandas==1.2.4
params-flow
patsy==0.5.3
pmdarima==2.0.2
prophet==1.1.1
pydeck==0.6.2
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.6.3
seaborn==0.11.1
statsmodels==0.13.5
streamlit==0.81.1
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorflow==2.5.0
```

getting below error:

```
#10 242.3 The conflict is caused by:
#10 242.3     The user requested numpy
#10 242.3     altair 4.1.0 depends on numpy
#10 242.3     cmdstanpy 1.0.8 depends on numpy>=1.21
#10 242.3     h5py 3.1.0 depends on numpy>=1.19.3; python_version >= "3.9"
#10 242.3     keras-preprocessing 1.1.2 depends on numpy>=1.9.1
#10 242.3     matplotlib 3.4.2 depends on numpy>=1.16
#10 242.3     opt-einsum 3.3.0 depends on numpy>=1.7
#10 242.3     pandas 1.2.4 depends on numpy>=1.16.5
#10 242.3     params-flow 0.8.2 depends on numpy
#10 242.3     patsy 0.5.3 depends on numpy>=1.4
#10 242.3     pmdarima 2.0.2 depends on numpy>=1.21.2
#10 242.3     prophet 1.1.1 depends on numpy>=1.15.4
#10 242.3     pydeck 0.6.2 depends on numpy>=1.16.4
#10 242.3     scikit-learn 0.24.2 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
#10 242.3     scipy 1.6.3 depends on numpy<1.23.0 and >=1.16.5
#10 242.3     seaborn 0.11.1 depends on numpy>=1.15
#10 242.3     statsmodels 0.13.5 depends on numpy>=1.17; python_version != "3.10" or 
platform_system != "Windows" or platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"
#10 242.3     streamlit 0.81.1 depends on numpy
#10 242.3     tensorboard 2.5.0 depends on numpy>=1.12.0
#10 242.3     tensorflow 2.5.0 depends on numpy~=1.19.2
#10 242.3
#10 242.3 To fix this you could try to:
#10 242.3 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
#10 242.3 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
#10 242.3
#10 242.3 ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --default-timeout=100 future pip &&  hash pip 
&&  pip install --upgrade pip &&  hash pip &&  pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I removed the packages version, then it tried to download multiple versions and getting timed out.

I have `python 3.9` in local system where i am creating `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

any suggestions what's going wrong?

Comment: can you please add requirements file as well?

Comment: @IkramKhanNiazi not able add full file, so added few top lines

Comment: @pc94 Can you try also with only the dependencies (e.g altair, cmdstanpy ..) you have in your above log error? If you still have the error you can add only those in the question instead of the whole list of dependencies which are not related with the issue. This can help us to reproduce the issue and try it in our local machines without asking you

Comment: @ggeop tried with only dependencies, got the same error. Also updated the same packages in question.

Comment: Can you run `pip check` in your local environment?

Comment: Should `numpy` have a specific version pin, like the other dependencies?  Is there anything Docker-specific about this issue, or do you run into the same problem running `pip install` in a clean non-Docker virtual environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze i tried numpy with specific version too, it was not working so i tried without pinning any version.
this does seem like docker specific issue, it is package compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error could be related with pip version. You are using different version of pip in your local system and in Docker image. Make sure you are using the same pip version with your local system.

You can try the following steps:

- `pip --version` in your local system to get the local version (`LOCAL_VERSION`)
- Then update the docker file with the specific version e.g `pip install --upgrade pip==LOCAL_VERSION`

Comment: it did not resolve the issue, getting the same error

Comment: @pc94 can you try without the `hash pip`?

Comment: i have tried it earlier, got the same error. Anyway this error is not related to `hash pip`.

Comment: @pc94 if you still having the problem another work around is to create a docker image from an ubuntu image instead of python

Answer (score 0):

These 2 constraints seem incompatible:

- `cmdstanpy 1.0.8 depends on numpy>=1.21`
- `tensorflow 2.5.0 depends on numpy~=1.19.2`

If I am not mistaken, `~=1.19.2` means `>= 1.19.2, == 1.19.*`, so it can not be anything in the in the `1.21` range (nor `1.20`, `1.22`, and so on) it has to be in `1.19.*` but greater than `1.19.2`.

To solve this you could try to recreate the `requirements.txt` file from scratch. Maybe create a new virtual environment, let `pip` install all (direct) dependencies without the pinned versions, and then in case `pip` does manage to install everything without encountering any conflict you can re-freeze this solution into a fresh `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: yes right, but let's say tensorflow is compatible with numpy 1.19.3 and i have install the numpy 1.19.3, now it is showing other packages are not compatible, as 
`altair 4.1.0 depends on numpy`
`cmdstanpy 1.0.8 depends on numpy>=1.21`

what should we do in this case?

Comment: Seems like that there is no solution. Either there is indeed an (indirect) incompatibility or maybe there is a mistake in a package metadata somewhere. -- If I were you I would try with a different Python version. -- Have you tried `pip check` in your reference environment (your local environment)?

Comment: yes i tried `pip check`, it is saying same thing: `tensorflow 2.5.0 depends on numpy~=1.19.2`

Comment: Can you use a different version of `tensorflow`, in other words can you change its pinned version in your requirements.txt? -- Alternative: can you create a new virtual environment, let pip install everything without pinned versions and (in the case pip manages to find a solution) re-freeze the result into `requirements.txt`?

Comment: This worked, i installed everything without pinned any versions and pip did the rest. Thanks